# Convert numpy arrays comprehensions to regular python syntax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am not sure if I have used the right term for the title, as I have never worked with python numpy module, but I have two lines from particular code, which confuse me:
These two:

```
IAM[theta == 0]=1
IAM[abs(theta) > 90 | (IAM < 0)]=0
```

source:
https://github.com/Sandia-Labs/PVLIB_Python/blob/master/pvlib/pvl_physicaliam.py#L109-111

I am wondering if they could be translated to a regular Python code?
Does upper two actually mean:

```
theta = 10  # for example

newIAM = []
for item in IAM:
    if item == 0:
       newIAM.append(1)
    else:
       newIAM.append(item)
```

and:

```
newIAM = []
for item in IAM:
    if (abs(theta) > 90) and (item < 0)
       newIAM.append(0)
    else:
       newIAM.append(item)
```

?

I am using python 2.7.
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IAM is a vector, theta can be a vector or a scalar.

```
IAM[theta == 0]=1
```

sets every value of IAM to 1 where the corresponding theta is zero.

```
IAM[abs(theta) > 90 | (IAM < 0)]=0
```

(it should) sets every value of IAM to 0 where the corresponding absolute theta value is bigger than 90 OR IAM is smaller than zero.

```
import numpy as np
IAM = np.array( [3, 2, 3, 4, 5] )
# theta can be shorter than IAM
theta = np.array( [0, 1, 0, 1])
IAM[theta==0] = 1
# when theta is a scalar only the fist value will be tested and perhaps changed
# theta[0] is 0 => set IAM[0] to 0
# theta[1] is not 0 => do not change IAM[1]
# ...
#IAM = [1 2 1 4 5]
```

The equivalent pure python solution:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
IAM = [3, 2, 3, 4, 5]
theta = [0, 1, 0, 1]
newIAM = []

try:
    for iam, t in izip_longest(IAM, theta):
        if t == 0:
            newIAM.append(1)
        else:
            newIAM.append(iam)
except TypeError:
    newIAM.extend(IAM)
    if theta == 0:
        neaIAM[0]=1
```

The second line does not work like intended.

```
import numpy as np
IAM = np.array( [-1, 2, 3, -5, 1])
theta = np.array( [1, 2, -91, 3, 4])
IAM[(abs(theta) > 90) | (IAM < 0)]=0
# IAM is [0, 2, 0, 0, 1]
```

Without the parenthesis arround abs(theta) > 90 it checks if abs(theta) is bigger than (90 | (IAM < 0)). 90 | (IAM < 0) evaluates to 90 if IAM >= 0 and to 91 if IAM < 0.

Seems like a bug in the code you posted